# Moving Visual Studio Installshield project from Windows XP to Windows 7

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, installshield

I have a Visual Studio project that compiles correctly on a `Windows XP` computer.  I have copied the entire project to another PC running `Windows 7` and it generates compilation errors.

The application uses `.NET Framework 4.0` and `Visual C++` redistributables, installed locally. It couldn't find these.

I realised that it was looking for the Microsoft.net in

```
c:\Program Files\Installshield\2012SpringLE\SetupPrerequisites
```

By right-clicking on the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 entry in the Redistributables (Installshield) window I was able to search for the merge module and corrected it to

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Installshield\2012SpringLE\SetupPrerequisites
```

That overcame the `.NET Framework 4.0` problem

However, I can't find the merge modules for the Visual C++ entry in the Redistributables (Installshield) window. Can anyone tell me where they are?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the big reasons that I suggest not only building on your machine.  A proper CI build system should run on any number of build servers.

For merge modules you need to look at your merge module search path found in Tools | Options | Merge Modules     Search those directories for your merge modules and copy them over to your new server.

For pretty much everything else you need to be aware of the Path Variables view (abstraction) what they are set to and how they are being used by various tables such as Binary, File, Icon and so on.

Personally I'm very meticulous when it comes to managing this and making sure everything is checked into source control properly.  InstallShield will allow you to do very bad things in this area and not warn you what you are doing is problematic.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2010 and there is no entry Merge Modules in Tools | Options.  The nearest I can find is Tools | Options | Projects and Solutions | VC++ Directories.  However, this says "VC++ Directories editing in Tools > Options has been deprecated. VC++ Directories are now available as a user property sheet that is added by default to all projects".  I can't find any appropriate property sheet in the project, other than the one I originally mentioned Redistributables (Installshield). I have searched all my drives for .msm files without success.

Comment: In InstallShield LE  it's INSTALLSHIELD LE | Options | Merge Module Options